# How many 80 lb bags of Quickrete do I need for my slab?

Tags: concrete

How many 80lb bags of Quickrete will it take for a 20’ x 12’ x4” slab?

Comment: Are you completing this yourself? Mix, pour, and finish? DIY? Is this for a cost comparison? If you could add some more details it will make it a more interesting read and thus a better question. Please also take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Unless you're off the grid (by which I mean the ready-mix network), you _don't_ want to do this from bags.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows a rather distinct lack of effort to research before answering.

Answer (score 3):

Use [their calculator](https://www.quikrete.com/calculator/main.asp)!

Enter the area (12x20 is 240 sqft) and the depth of your slab (4in). It will break it down into the required number of bags.

There are some good **alternatives** to mixing your own bags. See answers under the earlier question [Best way to source concrete for a long fence project](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/219748/best-way-to-source-concrete-for-a-long-fence-project/220761#220761)

For a project this size (I had a similar one) I was wisely advised to get a truck, pump and finishing crew. I have completed smaller sizes alone, with bags and a mixer.

Also note that if you are mixing this yourself, the time spread and mixing variations alone, for a large slab, might give you batch inconsistencies that can become an eyesore. But this is a matter of personal skills & priorities of course.

[image]

Comment: At least 10 men will be needed to mix and place the concrete.

Comment: It must all be poured in a few hours to avoid weak boundaries between batches.

Comment: @blacksmith37 yeah, or OP could form it in manageable sections but then you get separated wet cuts and likely unsightly small sections